# Maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python

```
def F(n):
    if n<3:
        return n + 1
    if n >= 3:
        if n%2==0:
            return n + 2*F(n+2)
        else:
            return F(n-2) + n - 2
c = 0
for i in range(1,10000):
    s = str(F(i))
    if len(s) == 3:
        c += 1
print(c)
```

Вывод программы:

File "main.py", line 6, in F
return n + 2*F(n+2)

File "main.py", line 6, in F

return n + 2*F(n+2)
File "main.py", line 6, in F
return n + 2*F(n+2)

File "main.py", line 6, in F

return n + 2*F(n+2)
File "main.py", line 6, in F
return n + 2*F(n+2)

File "main.py", line 6, in F

return n + 2*F(n+2)
File "main.py", line 6, in F
return n + 2*F(n+2)

File "main.py", line 6, in F

return n + 2*F(n+2)
File "main.py", line 6, in F
return n + 2*F(n+2)
File "main.py", line 2, in F
if n<3:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: По стеку вызовов видно, что у вас рекурсия пошла по ветке увеличения n, в итоге условие выхода из рекурсии (n < 3) не выполнилось, и программа прервалась аварийно из-за превышения максимальной глубины вызовов.

Answer (score 1):

Второе условие вызывает себя же в будущем. Поэтому если оно четно, то оно вызовет еще одну четную функцию, а она еще одну, т.е. так и не посчитает значение никогда.
Решается, дописав 10 строку:

```
def F(n):
    if n<3:
        return n + 1
    if n >= 3 and n%2==0:
            return n + 2*F(n+2)
    if n >= 3 and n%2!=0:
            return F(n-2) + n - 2
c = 0
for i in range (1,100):
    if i%2!=0:
        s = str(F(i))
        if len(s) == 3:
            c += 1
print(c)
```

Comment: Если вы знали ответ, то зачем задавали вопрос?

Comment: Узнал уже после того, как задал вопрос :D.

Comment: Между вопросом и вашим ответом прошло 14 минут. Т.е. вы даже их не потратили перед заходом на форум. В следующий раз лучше используйте их на самостоятельный поиск ответа, чем на набивку вопросов, ответ на которые так просто и быстро можно найти самому.

Answer (score 0):

Причина указана прямо в тексте ошибок.

Узнать заданное ограничение на глубину рекурсии можно так:

```
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

Установить нужную вам -  вот так:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(lim_of_recr)
```

Но советую быть с этим параметром поосторожнее. Поэтому лучше править алгоритм, а не давать возможность углубляться в рекурсию.